# Incompatibily between ruby and mysql gem

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

When trying to install the mysql gem from cPanel on my website, I get an error saying that the gem requires Ruby >= 1.8.6.
This is a shared server and the version of Ruby is 1.8.5 and can't be upgraded.
I do not have shell access and it seems the only way for me to install a gem is through the list of gems within cPanel.

How can I get mysql for my website?

Comment: Have you tried contacting your hoster ?

Comment: Yeah they were not helpful they told me I need to purchase a VPS plan. I'm trying to see if there is a way anyway.

Comment: What hosting service is this. That's ridiculous that they can't support the proper combinations. Also, they might be right that you should be on a VPS (but I understand that isn't helpful right now). I just wouldn't use their VPS service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one having answered how to install a gem without shell access, I'll assume it can't be done and so will accept my own answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to install an [older gem](http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=4550). 2.7.5 seems to be the proper version.

Comment: From what I can tell, the cPanel interface doesn't let me specify a version. If I enter mysql -v 2.7.5 for example it concatenates everything and tries to fetch a gem called mysqlv275.
And as I've mentionned above, I do not have shell access. Are there other ways for me to install gems?

Comment: When you install a reuby gem, does it just create a directory for the gem in the gems folder? If so, could I just get the gem files and upload them to the gems directory, or are there some settings taking place? I have access to the gems directory through the file browser in cPanel.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby 1.8.5 is pretty old and as far as I know hasn't been actively supported by Rails for a while. You really need 1.8.6 and preferably 1.8.7. If your host won't upgrade it may be time to look elsewhere. If you really have no other option, you should to what Yuval suggests and try installing an older version of the gem.